# Compute the coefficients

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I came upon an exercise which I can not find the solution. I am asked to find the coeffients $a_0$,$a_1$,$b_0$,$b_1$,with the method of undefined coefficients of the following expression 
 $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f(x)dx = h({a_0}{f_0}+{a_1}{f_1})+{h^2}({b_0}{f'_0} + {b_1}{f'_1})$
 where ${f'_i} = {f'(x_i)} $ and $x_i = x_0 + ih $.
 
  I tried to look into bibliography and all I have found is 
$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f(x)dx = h/2[{f_0} + {f_1]} $ 
 but I am not sure how to use this when no $f'$ is in the proof. Also does $f$ have to be polynomial. Because I think that's missing from the exercise and is a key to my proof.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is a 2nd degree polynomial. What can you do with the expression?

Comment: @Somos yes but can we do this if we do not even know that it is a polynomial function. And how do we prove it in the end if it actually a polynomial?